# При конвертации изображения с помощью ImageMagick оно осветляется

Tags: color, imagemagick

Ubuntu 14.04.03

ImageMagick 6.7.7.10

Исходное изображение CMYK

Конвертирую в PNG

Делаю так:

> convert f2856e00-c95a-4f22-b929-d84041520748
>   png:f2856e00-c95a-4f22-b929-d84041520748_m.png

Если я это делаю на Ubuntu 14.04 то изображение становится более светлым, но если на Ubuntu 12.04 (ImageMagick 6.6.9-7) или на MacOS ( ImageMagick 6.9.3) то все нормально.

Покопавшись заметил, что если указать профили, то конвертация пройдет нормально

> convert -profile
>   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/iccprofiles/default_cmyk.icc
>   f2856e00-c95a-4f22-b929-d84041520748 -profile
>   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/iccprofiles/default_rgb.icc
>   f2856e00-c95a-4f22-b929-d84041520748_m.png

Хочется понять, как бы сделать так, что б конвертация происходила без искажения цвета. Может указать где эти профили в конфигурационных файлах?

Answer (score 1):

в моем случае все решилось просто. версия ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 видимо имеет такой баг. обновил до версии 6.9.3 и все стало хорошо (обновлял вручную, в репозиториях такой версии нет)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже задумывался над этим. Но скорее всего нет. Так как профили CMYK и RGB бывают разные. В моем случае, допустим, от дефолтного профиля профита никакого, пришлось брать Адобовские профили.